# (android) error when build apk :

Tags: android

Logcat error:

```
: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.clas
```

the gradle app code ::

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.esrae.rainbow"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
    }

}

dependencies {

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terminal execute in root project folder:

```
./gradlew clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your dependencies all are of the same version, use this in place of your dependencies.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'
```

In your code, you were using,

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'
```

Change this to

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:10.0.1'
```

And in your Projects's gradle use this.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Esraa Ragab, Please try this, and let me know if the issue is still there. Thanks.

Comment: i have this error
Error:(34, 13) Failed to resolve: com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:10.0.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/esrae/Desktop/Rainbow/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: Please do post your both gradle dependency. By both I mean, app's and Project's.

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'


        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: @EsraaRagab You should post a new question for the new error.

Comment: Esraa Ragab, I just updated my answer, please check this, and do let me know if this helps.